# post an array and iterate throught it in PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This is the first time i create my own webservice (someone always did it for me before), so please bear with me.

I post this array :

```
    $data = array(
        'user_id' => $this->post('user_id'),
        'group_id' => $this->post('group_id'),
        'child_id' => $this->post('child_id'), //will be nested array
        'custom' =>  $this->post('custom'),
        'time' => $this->post('time'),
        'date' => $this->post('date')
    );
```

I tried to create a nested array with this : `$this->post('child_id')`, because user can post multiple `child_id` at once.

Then i tried to iterate through the `child_id`, because i need to insert them to the mysql :

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data['child_id']); $i++)
            {
                $result2 = $this->schedule_m->add_trans('transaction_schedule', $data, $result_id[0]['id']);
            }
```

What should i do, so i can have an array of `child_id` in my `$data` array? (nested array)

And how to iterate through it?

**UPDATE :**
I have updated the codes above.

I use `advanced rest client` for testing, and i tried to post something like this in the `form` content type :

```
child_id=1&user_id=1&group_id=1&custom=&time=17%3A17%3A00&date=&child_id=2
```

Notice that theres two child_id (left most and right most), but only the last one (right most) is inserted.

And this is the `add_trans` in the model :

```
function add_trans($table, $data, $schedule_id) {
    $query = $this->db->insert($table, array('child_id' => $data['child_id'], 'schedule_id' => $schedule_id));
    return $query;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Try `$this->post('child_id')` - remove `[]`

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili Thanks. But i need it to be an array..What should i do?

Comment: you should change child_id[] to child_id and then count it to use in loop.

Comment: @MobasherFasihy Wait..do u mean it automatically becomes an array?

Comment: You use `child_id[]` in only html, to make it able hold multiple items, but on the server you use `child_id` which would be holding all items you set in html, you can also show as html part, to check if there is any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even thought you set the name attribute as `child[]` on the markup,

You still need to call it as:

```
'child_id' => $this->post('child_id')
```

It will still return an array.

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data['child_id']); $i++) {
    $result2 = $this->schedule_m->add_trans('transaction_schedule', $data, $result_id[0]['id']);
}
```

EDIT:

Looking upon you query string, that seems to be the culprit:

```
child_id=1&user_id=1&group_id=1&custom=&time=17%3A17%3A00&date=&child_id=2
 ^ same index , same index, same index, it will overwrite and you will get only `2`
```

If you want to get them all into an array format, you need to set them like this

```
child_id[]=1&user_id=1&group_id=1&custom=&time=17%3A17%3A00&date=&child_id[]=2
        ^ it needs to be set like this
```

UPDATE:

And in your model, if you want each id per row, well you can also loop in this case:

```
function add_trans($table, $data, $schedule_id) {
    foreach($data['child_id'] as $child_id) {
        $query = $this->db->insert($table, array('child_id' => $child_id, 'schedule_id' => $schedule_id));  
    }

    // return $this->db->insert_id();
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I followed your suggestion, and tried to post 2 child_id. However, only the last one is inserted. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @BlazeTama before i update my answer, what does `add_trans()` do? how does it insert the data?

Comment: I will put it on my question in a second

Comment: @BlazeTama you need to query string to be formatted, check also my revision

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried it, but i got 500 error : Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'</p><p>INSERT INTO `transaction_schedule` (`child_id`, `schedule_id`) VALUES (Array, '28'). It seems child_id[] become a array (instead of 1 and 2) when the model tried to insert it to the DB.

Comment: This is the form i post : child_id%5B%5D=8&user_id=1&group_id=1&custom=&time=17%3A17%3A00&date=&child_id%5B%5D=9 ([] become %5B%5D in RAW format)

Comment: @BlazeTama yes, you're already there, it means that the query string is correct, and now you got an array (multiple values), check my edit on the model too

Answer (score 1):

ofcourse that won't work, it has to be

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($data['child_id']); $i++)
{
      $result2 = $this->schedule_m->add_trans('transaction_schedule', $data['child_id'][$i], $result_id[0]['id']);
}
```

because you've not set $data['child_id[]'] so it doesn't exist, the key is just a string or number, it does not validate or parse anything

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to give `child[]` in post method. just give only child, it will get complete array what are you sending from views

replace

```
 'child_id' => $this->post('child_id[]')
```

with

```
'child_id' => $this->post('child_id')
```